# NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic tf.Tensor (Log_2:0) to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have the following code which is based on https://github.com/leonard-seydoux/scatnet. The original code was based on TF v1 and I am in the process of migrating it to TF v2. However, I am facing some issues while trying to perform a numpy operation on a tensor. I am running the code on Google Colab.

The reproducible code is as below, sorry it is quite long:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

from datetime import datetime
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

HERMITE = [[1, 0, -3, 2], [0, 0, 3, -2], [0, 1, -2, 1], [0, 0, -1, 1]]
FORMAT = 'float32'

def real_hermite_interp(xi, x, m, p):
    # Hermite polynomial coefficients
    h = tf.Variable(np.array(HERMITE).astype(FORMAT), trainable=False)
    xx = tf.stack([x[:, :-1], x[:, 1:]], axis=2)

    # The concatenated coefficients are of shape (n_knots - 1, 2)
    mm = tf.stack([m[:-1], m[1:]], axis=1)
    pp = tf.stack([p[:-1], p[1:]], axis=1)

    y = tf.concat([mm, pp], axis=1)

    # Extract Hermite polynomial coefficients from y (n_knots - 1, 4)
    yh = tf.matmul(y, h)

    xi_ = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(xi, 0), 0)
    x0_ = tf.expand_dims(xx[:, :, 0], 2)
    x1_ = tf.expand_dims(xx[:, :, 1], 2)
    xn = (xi_ - x0_) / (x1_ - x0_)

    # Calculate powers of normalized interpolation vector
    mask = tf.logical_and(tf.greater_equal(xn, 0.), tf.less(xn, 1.))
    mask = tf.cast(mask, tf.float32)
    xp = tf.pow(tf.expand_dims(xn, -1), [0, 1, 2, 3])

    # Interpolate
    return tf.einsum('rf,srtf->st', yh, xp * tf.expand_dims(mask, -1))

class Scattering:
    """Learnable scattering network layer."""

    def __init__(self, x, j=None, q=None, k=None, pooling_type='average',
                 decimation=2, pooling=2, index=0, **filters_kw):
        """Scattering network layer.

        Computes the convolution modulus and scattering coefficients of the
        input signal.

        Arguments
        ---------
            x: :class:`~tensorflow.Tensor()`
                Input data of shape ``(batch_size, channels, patch_shape).
        """
        # Filter bank properties
        self.shape_input = x.get_shape().as_list()
        self.j = j = j[index] if type(j) is list else j
        self.q = q = q[index] if type(q) is list else q
        self.k = k = k[index] if type(k) is list else k

        filters = self.init_filters(j, q, k, **filters_kw)
        n_filters, kernel_size = filters.get_shape().as_list()
        filters_concat = tf.concat([tf.math.real(filters), tf.math.imag(filters)], 0)
        filters_kernel = tf.expand_dims(tf.transpose(filters_concat), 1)

        # Pad input in the time dimension before convolution with half the size
        # of filters temporal dimension (kernel_size).
        shape_fast = [np.prod(self.shape_input[:-1]), 1, self.shape_input[-1]]
        paddings = [0, 0], [0, 0], [kernel_size // 2 - 1, kernel_size // 2 + 1]
        x_reshape = tf.reshape(x, shape_fast)
        x_pad = tf.pad(x_reshape, paddings=paddings, mode='SYMMETRIC')

        # Differentiate the case of one input channel or multiple
        # which needs reshaping in order to treat them independently
        # The "NCW" format stores data as batch_shape + [in_channels, in_width]
        x_conv = tf.nn.conv1d(x_pad, filters_kernel, stride=decimation,
                              padding='VALID', data_format='NCW')
        u = tf.sqrt(tf.square(x_conv[:, :n_filters]) +
                    tf.square(x_conv[:, n_filters:]))
        self.u = tf.reshape(u, (*self.shape_input[:-1], n_filters, -1))

        pool = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling1D

        # Pooling for the scattering coefficients
        if pooling > 1:
            pooled = pool(
                pooling // (decimation ** (index + 1)),
                pooling // (decimation ** (index + 1)),
                padding='valid', data_format='channels_first')
            pooled = pooled(u)

        self.s = tf.reshape(pooled, self.shape_input[:-1] + [j * q] + [-1])   
        self.output = self.s

        tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
        inverse = tf.gradients(x_conv, x, x_conv)[0]

        self.reconstruction_loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(
            inverse - tf.stop_gradient(x)) / np.prod(self.shape_input)

    def init_filters(self, j, q, k, learn_scales=False, learn_knots=False,
                     learn_filters=True, hilbert=False):
        extra_octave = 1 if learn_scales else 0
        self.filter_samples = k * 2 ** (j + extra_octave)

        time_max = np.float32(k * 2**(j - 1 + extra_octave))
        time_grid = tf.linspace(-time_max, time_max, self.filter_samples)

        scales_base = 2**(tf.range(j * q, dtype=tf.float32) / np.float32(q))
        scales_delta = tf.Variable(
            tf.zeros(j * q), trainable=learn_scales, name='scales')
        scales = scales_base + scales_delta

        nyquist_offset = scales + \
            tf.stop_gradient(tf.one_hot(0, j * q) * tf.nn.relu(1 - scales[0]))
        scales_correction = tf.concat(
            [tf.zeros(1),
             tf.nn.relu(nyquist_offset[:-1] - nyquist_offset[1:])], 0)
        self.scales = nyquist_offset + \
            tf.stop_gradient(tf.cumsum(scales_correction))

        knots_base = tf.Variable(
            tf.ones(k), trainable=learn_knots, name='knots')

        knots_sum = tf.cumsum(
            tf.clip_by_value(
                tf.expand_dims(knots_base, 0) * tf.expand_dims(self.scales, 1),
                1, self.filter_samples - k), exclusive=True, axis=1)
        self.knots = knots_sum - (k // 2) * tf.expand_dims(self.scales, 1)

        if hilbert is True:
            m = (np.cos(np.arange(k) * np.pi) * np.hamming(k)).astype(FORMAT)
            p = (np.zeros(k)).astype(FORMAT)
            self.m = tf.Variable(m, name='m', trainable=learn_filters)
            self.p = tf.Variable(p, name='p', trainable=learn_filters)

            # Boundary Conditions and centering
            mask = np.ones(k, dtype=np.float32)
            mask[0], mask[-1] = 0, 0
            m_null = self.m - tf.reduce_mean(self.m[1:-1])
            filters = real_hermite_interp(
                time_grid, self.knots, m_null * mask, self.p * mask)

            # Renorm and set filter-bank
            filters_renorm = filters / tf.reduce_max(filters, 1, keepdims=True)
            filters_fft = tf.signal.rfft(filters_renorm) # was spectral.rfft
            filters = tf.signal.ifft(
                tf.concat([filters_fft, tf.zeros_like(filters_fft)], 1))

        # Define the parameters for saving
        self.parameters = self.m, self.p, self.scales, self.knots
        return filters

    def renorm(self, parent, epsilon=1e-3):
        # Extract all shapes.
        if epsilon > 0:
            s = self.s / (tf.expand_dims(parent.s, -2) + epsilon)
            batch_size, *_, samples = s.get_shape().as_list()
            return tf.reshape(s, [batch_size, -1, samples])
        else:
            return tf.reshape(self.s, [batch_size, -1, samples])

# testing
data = tf.random.uniform((4,3,16800), dtype=tf.float32)
batch_size = 4

args = {'layers': {'j': [4, 6, 8], 'q': [8, 2, 1], 'k': 7, 'pooling_type': 'average', 'decimation': 4, 'pooling': 1024, 'learn_scales': False, 'learn_knots': False, 'learn_filters': True, 'hilbert': True}, 'eps_norm': 0.001, 'eps_log': 0.0001, 'learning': {'epochs': 3, 'rate': 0.001}, 'pca': {'n_components': 5}, 'gmm': {'gmm_type': 'natural', 'trainable': False}, 'gmm_init': {'n_components': 10, 'max_iter': 1000, 'covariance_type': 'full', 'warm_start': True}}

# Run over batches
epochs = args['learning']['epochs']
learning_rate = args['learning']['rate']
for epoch in range(epochs):

  # Gradually decrease learning rate over epochs
  if epoch == epochs // 2:
      learning_rate /= 5
  if epoch == 3 * epochs // 4:
      learning_rate /= 5

  # Calculate scattering coefficients for all batches
  scat_all = list()
  n_batches = data.shape[0] // batch_size
  for b in range(n_batches):
    layers = [Scattering(data, index=0, **args['layers'])]
    for i in range(1, 3):
      layer = Scattering(layers[-1].u, index=i, **args['layers'])
      layers.append(layer)

    # Extract parameters.
    net = [layer.parameters for layer in layers]

    # Get reconstruction losses.
    rl = tf.add_n([a.reconstruction_loss for a in layers])

    # Renormalize coefficients.
    r = list()
    for i in range(1, 3):
        r.append(layers[i].renorm(layers[i - 1], args['eps_norm']))

    # Concatenate.
    sx = tf.transpose(tf.concat(r, axis=1), [1, 0, 2])
    sx = tf.reshape(sx, [sx.get_shape().as_list()[0], -1])
    sx = tf.transpose(sx)
    sx = tf.math.log(sx + args['eps_log'])

    sx[np.isnan(sx)] = np.log(args['eps_log'])
    sx[np.isinf(sx)] = np.log(args['eps_log'])
    scat_all.append(sx)
```

The issue is from the line 'sx[np.isnan(sx)] = np.log(args['eps_log'])'. The full error is shown below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [6], line 34
     31 print("sx:", sx)
     32 print("sx shape: ", sx.shape)
---> 34 sx[np.isnan(sx)] = np.log(args['eps_log'])
     35 sx[np.isinf(sx)] = np.log(args['eps_log'])
     36 scat_all.append(sx)

File c:\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:922, in Tensor.__array__(***failed resolving arguments***)
    920 def __array__(self, dtype=None):
    921   del dtype
--> 922   raise NotImplementedError(
    923       f"Cannot convert a symbolic tf.Tensor ({self.name}) to a numpy array."
    924       f" This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to"
    925       f" a NumPy call, which is not supported.")

NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic tf.Tensor (Log_2:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported.
```

Based on solutions on previous stackoverflow posts, I have tried to upgrade my tensorflow (2.11.0) and numpy versions (1.23.5) but that did not solve the problem. I saw some suggestions on downgrading numpy but because of other dependencies that did not work. My Python version is 3.8.16. Any suggestions on how to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 456 lines of code are hardly [mre].

Comment: Maybe you should use "tf.log" instead if "np.log" (at line 34)? Otherwise you need to figure out how to convert tf.Tensor to numpy array. The error message says that automatic conversion is not done.

Comment: Does `symbolic tensor` mean anything to you?

Comment: @AndreasKaufmann Thanks for your reply. In the process of trying out your suggestion, I discovered that the issue should be stemming from 'inverse = tf.gradients(x_conv, x, x_conv)[0]' inside 'class Scattering'. In TF v2, the original code would not run without me adding 'tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()'. And because of this conversion from tensor to numpy array using numpy() seems to be not working as well bc of eager execution

Comment: @hpaulj I now think the issue is because while migrating from v1 to v2 I had to disable eager execution for the gradient function to work inside class Scattering and somehow that changed the nature of the tensor but not too sure why